# Need help on developing an array or function which will be able to carry over the choices you made

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a school project which requires developing an interactive menu. I have limited knowledge on many aspects of JavaScript and html as I've been learning it for a couple of months. I am making a uniform menu which allows the user to theoretically buy uniform items (i'm not actually adding in payment options).

I need help on being able to create a function or something similar which will display the choices you have made and also carry over the choices you made, which will result a confirm message.

[image: For example]

In the above screenshot, pretend a user wanted 2 small blazers. So the user would click on small and click on enter quantity and type in 2. The user would then click on confirm order which will bring up a confirm message like

```
You have chosen to confirm 2 small sized blazers for $400. Confirm?
```

The problem is I don't know how to create this message which varies on what size and how many items a user wants.

Sample code in [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GpLvR/): Sorry if this doesn't quite make much sense. I've tried my best at explaining my problem so I might have missed out important details. So if I did, please tell.

**HTML:**

```
    <td>Blazer (All Sizes) - $200</td>
    <td><button onclick="small()">Small</button> 
    <p><button onclick="medium()">Medium</button>  </p>
    <button onclick="large()">Large</button> </td>
    <td><button onclick="quantitynumber()">Enter Quantity</button> </td>
    <td><button onclick="confirmorder()">Confirm Order</button>
```

**JS:**

```
var blz = 0  
function small()
  {
      blz = confirm ('You have selected size: Small. Confirm?')
  }
   function medium()
  {
      blz = confirm ('You have selected size: Medium. Confirm?')
  }
   function large()
  {
      blz = confirm ('You have selected size: Large. Confirm?')
  }

 function quantitynumber()
 {
     blz = prompt ('Enter the number of Blazer(s) to order')
     blz1 = blz * 200
        if ( blz == 1) {
    blz1 = confirm ('You have chosen to order 1 Blazer for $' + blz1 + '. Confirm?')
    }

            else if ( blz >=2  && blz <= 5) {
    blz1 = confirm ('You have chosen to order ' + blz + ' Blazers for $' + blz1 + '. Confirm?')         
    }

    else if (blz >5) {
        alert('There is a limit of 5 Blazers per customer.')
        blz = null
        blz1= null
    }
    else if (blz = isNaN || blz == '') {
        alert ('Please type in a valid number.')
    }

 }
function confirmorder()
{
    if (blz == small && blz >= 1 && blz <= 5) {
    blz1 = confirm ('You have chosen to confirm ' + blz + ' small sized Blazers for $' + blz1 + '. Confirm?')
    }

}
```

Comment: Sample code in jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/GpLvR/
Sorry if this doesn't quite make much sense. I've tried my best at explaining my problem so I might have missed out important details. So if I did, please tell.

Comment: Please include the code (and fiddle link) inside the question too.

Comment: A couple of observations.. **1** change the 2nd drop-down in the jsfiddle from `onLoad` to `No wrap in <head>` **2** selections which (a) must be made and (b) have a number of options are typically done with a radio-button - you can _visibly_ force a default choice if the user doesn't make one then **3** The result of the javascript function `confirm` is either `true` or `false` - blz will be `undefined` if no choice is made, or `true` if a choice is made and confirmed, finally being `false` if a choice is made but not confirmed.

Comment: @Iced-Z thanks for acceptin my answer... and uh.. good luck on the school project... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

since you just have a finite set of values..  3 sizes of blazers.. and quantity cannot be greater than 5... i think.. a better solution would be to let the user choose from a limited set of options..

example: [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/GpLvR/3/)

```
<table border="1" >
<tr>
<td>Blazer (All Sizes) - $200</td>
    <td>Size:
    <select id="blz_size" > 
        <option value="small"  >Small </option>
        <option value="medium"  >Medium </option>
        <option value="large"  >Large</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td>Quantity: 
     <select id="blz_quantity" > 
        <option value="1" >1 </option>
        <option value="2" >2</option>
        <option value="3" >3</option>
        <option value="4" >4</option>
        <option value="5" >5</option>
        </select>
    </td>
    <td><input type="button" onclick="confirmorder()" value="Confirm Order" /> </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<script type="text/javascript" >
function confirmorder()
{
var blz_size = document.getElementById('blz_size').value;
var blz_quan = document.getElementById('blz_quantity').value;
    var total = blz_quan * 200 ;
var choice = confirm ('You have chosen to order ' + blz_quan + ' ' + blz_size + ' sized Blazers for $' + total + '. Confirm?' );

    if(choice) {
     // do whatever you have to here...  
      alert("Order Confirmed");
    }
    else {
     return false;   
    }

}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick solution would be to create an array of order Objects. You can use the array.push() function to push your orders onto a variable length array. This would allow you to keep track of multiple orders without having to know anything beforehand. You could then loop through all of your orders and formulate your message accordingly.

```
function order(item,quan,price)
{
    this.item = item;
    this.quan = quan;
    this.price = price;
}

var orders = [];

orders.push(new order("shirt",50,200));

alert("You have chosen to confirm " + orders[0].quan + " " + orders[0].item + "(s) for " + orders[0].price + ". Confirm?");
```